# How to use multiple token using Regex Expression

Tags: python, regex

To extract first three letters 'abc' and three sets of three-digits numbers in `000_111_222` I am using the following expression:

```
text = 'abc_000_111_222'
print re.findall('^[a-z]{3}_[0-9]{3}_[0-9]{3}_[0-9]{3}', text)
```

But the expression returns empty list when instead of underscores there are minuses or periods used instead: `abc.000.111.222` or `abc-000-111-222` or any combination of it like: `abc_000.111-222`

Sure I could use a simple replace method to unify the text variable `text=text.replace('-','_').replace('.','_')`

But I wonder if instead of replacing I could modify regex expression that would recognize the underscores, minuses and periods.

Comment: Replace the underscore with something that matches any of the three characters?

Comment: few more sample strings will shed more light on what you try to achieve

Comment: `print re.findall(r'^[a-z]{3}(?:[_.-]\d{3}){3}$', text)` should work

Comment: @anubhava, the pattern can be repeated only twice since the string doesn't end with `_`

Comment: No, there is a `_` before first number as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regex character classes with `[`...`]`. For your case, it can be `[_.-]` (note the hyphen at the end, if it isn't at the end, it will be considered as a range like `[a-z]`).

You can use a regex like this:

```
print re.findall('^[a-z]{3}[_.-][0-9]{3}[_.-][0-9]{3}[_.-][0-9]{3}', text)
```

[image]

Btw, you can shorten your regex to have something like this:

```
print re.findall('^[a-z]{3}[_.-](\d{3}[_.-]){2}\d{3}', text)
```

Just as a comment, in case you want to match the same separator, then you can use capture groups and reference its content like this:

```
^[a-z]{3}([_.-])[0-9]{3}\1[0-9]{3}\1[0-9]{3}
```

Comment: Terrific answer! Thanks!

Comment: @alphanumeric glad to help

Answer (score -1):

Why not abandon `regexes` altogether, and use a clearer and simpler solution?

```
$ cat /tmp/tmp.py
SEP = '_.,;-=+'

def split_str(text):
    for s in list(SEP):
        res = text.split(s)
        if len(res) > 1:
            return text.split(s)

print(split_str('abc_000_111_222'))
print(split_str('abc;000;111;222'))
print(split_str('abc.000.111.222'))
print(split_str('abc-000-111-222'))
```

Which gives:

```
$ python3 /tmp/tmp.py
['abc', '000', '111', '222']
['abc', '000', '111', '222']
['abc', '000', '111', '222']
['abc', '000', '111', '222']

$
```